# stripe payment icons on small wordpress

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I ask for advice on how to reset my problem on wordpress.
I have a problem with the stripe payment, as you can see on my website [www.bmhotellerie.it](http://www.bmhotellerie.it) during the stripe payment the icons are small and you cannot enter the payment data correctly, ask for advice on how to increase the icons.
I kindly ask for all the changes to be made step by step.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following css in your theme style css file.

```
#stripe-payment-data p.form-row.woocommerce-SavedPaymentMethods-saveNew,
#stripe-payment-data #wc-stripe-cc-form .form-row {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I posted a new question, could you give me some advice?